# How to subtract 24 hour clock in JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two time values that should subtract and output the difference in hours. For example I get the values in this format:

```
0530-2400
```

That value is a string. I guess that converting to JavaScript `Date` object is the first step. Here is what I have so far:

```js
var time = "0530-2400",
    arr = [];
arr = time.split('-');

var dateObj = new Date(),
    hours1 = dateObj.setHours(Number(arr[0].substring(0, 2))),
    hours2 = dateObj.setHours(Number(arr[1].substring(0, 2))),
    minutes1 = dateObj.setMinutes(Number(arr[0].substring(2, 4))),
    minutes2 = dateObj.setMinutes(Number(arr[1].substring(2, 4)));
    
console.log(hours1);
console.log(minutes1);
console.log(hours2);
console.log(minutes2);
```

The output for the time I showed above should be `18.5` hours. If we subtract `24-5.5(530) = 18.5`

The increments are always on 15,30 or 45 minutes. Is there a good way to convert string and then do the math in JS?

Comment: `(+time.substr(5,2) + time.substr(7,2)/60) - (+time.substr(0,2) + time.substr(2,2)/60)` is the one-liner way of doing it, assuming your input format is always valid, and that the end time is always later than the start time (ie. not early the next day)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty First obstacle is to get hours and minutes from JS date object. As you can see in my example that's the first thing that I couldn't get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there cannot be hours spanning multiple days, you can do it using simple math:

```js
var time = "0530-2400",
    difference = calcDifference(time);

console.log(difference);

function calcDifference(time) {
  var arr = time.split('-').map(function(str) {
    var hours   = parseInt(str.substr(0, 2), 10),
        minutes = parseInt(str.substr(2, 4), 10);
    return (hours * 60 + minutes) / 60;
  });
  return arr[1] - arr[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
var time = "0530-2400",
arr = [];
arr = time.split('-');

var date1 = new Date(), date2 = new Date();
date1.setHours(Number(arr[0].substring(0, 2)));
date2.setHours(Number(arr[1].substring(0, 2)));
date1.setMinutes(Number(arr[0].substring(2, 4)));
date2.setMinutes(Number(arr[1].substring(2, 4)));
    
var msInAHour = 1000*60*60;
var msDiff = date2 - date1;
var diffInHours = msDiff/msInAHour;

console.log(diffInHours.toFixed(1));
```

Hint: It's a lot easier to work with dates if you use Moment.js.

Here: https://momentjs.com/

Here's a more advanced version of the code:

```js
var dt = "0530-2400".split('-')
  .map(e=>new Date('1980-01-01'+e.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})/," $1:$2")));  
  
var diffInHours = ((dt[1]-dt[0])/(3600000)).toFixed(1);
console.log(diffInHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalmin = 18.5*60
var min = total % 60;
var hours = (totalmin - min)/ 60;
```

> min: 30, hours: 18

If you want to convert military hours to standard:

```
if (hours > 0 && hours <= 12) {
  var standardHours= "" + hours;
} else if (hours > 12) {
  var standardHours= "" + (hours - 12);
} else if (hours == 0) {
  var standardHours= "12";
}
```

> standardHours: 6